# How are tabs numbers 'tabId' assigned in Chrome? Forwards or backwards, or maybe time based?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

building a chrome extension, and would like to make sure the extension is only launched from a specific domain.

My plan was to just do a chrome.tabs.get, and then, somewhere in those parameters collect the url.

Trouble is, I am not sure which tabId to grab.  0 will return the popup.html itself, and 1 appears to throw an error.

I looked through Google's API for Extensions, but didn't see a clear explanation for how the tabs are specifically numbered.

Thanks!